# Batch Script - FOR /D loop with wildcard folder issue

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008-r2

I have the following simple batch file:

```
FOR /D /r %%G IN (david\*\work) DO (
forfiles /P "%%G" /S /M *.* /D -7 /C "cmd /c del @PATH"
)
```

Problem is that it does not like the * as a wildcard in my path location in the first line, it says cannot find the path specified. I have multiple randomly named subfolders inside "david\" with a "work" folder in each of them -eg:

```
david\GSTR\work
david\WINDOWS\work
etc
```

How do I resolve this middle wildcard folder?

Note: even if I replace my command in the for loop with "echo %%G", it does not work.

Comment: when using `for /r` the wildcards are valid only when at the end of the pattern.

Comment: Try `for /D %%D in ("david\*") do for /D %%C in ("%%~D\work") do ( ... )`. Wildcards can only be used for the last path element, and `for /R` does not work with paths between `(`/`)`, you can only put pure names there...

Comment: Thanks aschipfl, this works