# For Loop /D Not Working for Network Attached Drives

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, batch-processing, drive

TLDR:  When I do the following For Loop in the CMD line, I get different results depending on what disk is Current.

```
for /d %i in (*) do @echo %i
```

It works if I am on any directory in the C: drive.

However, on any of my network attached drives, any directory, it won't work - there is no information provided - just goes back to the CMD prompt.

*Edit:
I originally incorrectly described this as USB attached drives - these are network attached drives (connected via USB to an old wifi router which is Ethernet wire connected to my computer).  They are mapped to specific drive letters, not defined by UNC path. I have updated the Subject Line and the Body*

Longer Explanation:

I've been successfully using a simple Batch file I created well over a year ago that would take any files in the Current directory and 7zip them.

I would just double-click the BAT file within File Explorer to launch it.

Yesterday, it stopped working.

At first I thought it was just that the BAT file wasn't recognized, and followed this and associated links:

- https://superuser.com/questions/53948/how-do-i-restore-bat-files-association-with-the-system-make-them-run-when-doub

I rebooted just in case that was needed for it to take effect.

That didn't fix the problem.

I copied the BAT contents (one line - adjusted for CMD line use) into the CMD line, and for the affected drives it would replicate/echo that line of code but the /D was just a /.

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z -m0=LZMA2 -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=64m -mmt16 "%%X.7z" "%%X\"
```

However, when testing, I accidentally found that line worked perfectly on a C: drive directory!!  I then tested the BAT file for C: drive - worked perfectly too!

I've found several questions on StackOverflow that are close, but not quite what my problem is - these were the closest:

- [Batch Script - FOR /D loop with wildcard folder issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49007372/batch-script-for-d-loop-with-wildcard-folder-issue)
- [Batch file for loop /D flag not appearing in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130576/batch-file-for-loop-d-flag-not-appearing-in-command-line)
- [Why is the letter D from /D option of command FOR missing in the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57535158/why-is-the-letter-d-from-d-option-of-command-for-missing-in-the-output#)

User JosefZ seems to be onto the problem, but hasn't found a solution yet (several years now).

I narrowed it down to the following CMD line snippet to simplify testing the issue.

```
for /d %i in (*) do @echo %i
```

Result is slightly different for the affected drives - it doesn't show anything, just goes to a CMD prompt.  C: is perfect.

BTW, I can run 7z directly on each individual file no matter the location, so that is not an issue.

*Update:  I can move, copy, delete individual files and groups of files betwixt the networked drives and the C: drive.*

I'm guessing that it comes down to the /D function - for some reason it fails on the attached drives, but not the C: system drive.

I'm hoping for some ideas, short of reinstalling Windows 10.

Well, I might create a Power Automate Desktop Flow instead, making individual call to 7z for each file in a directory. A bit more of a pain to run though.

Still, I have no idea the cause nor a way out.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Irrespective of all of that, I would rarely use `For /D %G In (*) Do ...` over `For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %G In ('Dir /A:D-H /B 2^>NUL') Do ...`

Comment: Are you sure you are in the directory you think? What is returned when you just put `cd` before?

Comment: @aschipfl - thanks, but I did use the `cd /d path` before running the line of commands to make sure the Current location was correct.

Comment: @Compo - thanks.  I will look at `/F` approach and determine what I need to update.  That said, I don't anticipate that this alone will solve this issue (unless I am missing something - very possible - if so, please do explain a bit more for me).  Nice tip though.

Comment: Side note to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74902319/for-loop-d-not-working-for-network-attached-drives?noredirect=1#comment132194385_74902319), please use `CD /D "path"`, or often better, `PushD "path"`, _(note the doublequotes)_.